# My first code on SQL is throwing an error

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn SQL through Oracle Live SQL. The following is my first code. Kindly help me with the error

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(    
    PersonID int,    
    LastName varchar(255),    
    FirstName varchar(255),    
    Address varchar(255),    
    City varchar(255)     
)

INSERT INTO Persons (Person ID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)   
VALUES (103980, 'Ramanathan', 'Arun', 'Chennai', 'India')
```

I get this error:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: In Oracle, you should use `varchar2()` rather than `varchar()`.

Comment: not Person ID it was PersonID

Comment: Hello Gordon,
I have updated the code as mentioned but still the error is throwing
CREATE TABLE Persons (      
    PersonID int,      
    LastName varchar2(255),      
    FirstName varchar2(255),      
    Address varchar2(255),      
    City varchar2(255)       
)     
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)     
VALUES (103980, 'Ramanathan', 'Arun', 'Chennai', 'India') 

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a space in `Person ID` in insert code (line 8)
user `PersonID` instead of `Person ID`

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (    
    PersonID int,    
    LastName varchar(255),    
    FirstName varchar(255),    
    Address varchar(255),    
    City varchar(255)     
);



INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)   
VALUES (103980, 'Ramanathan', 'Arun', 'Chennai', 'India')
```

Comment: Answers like these which really don't add any value to the website only to the op could be placed into the comments.

Comment: Hello Hesam,
I have updated the code accordingly but still in coming.
CREATE TABLE Persons (      
    PersonID int,      
    LastName varchar2(255),      
    FirstName varchar2(255),      
    Address varchar2(255),      
    City varchar2(255)       
)     
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)     
VALUES (103980, 'Ramanathan', 'Arun', 'Chennai', 'India') 

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: the code in this answer worked without error,
use ";" in line 7